# PHP return an pagination object and displaying the links when called

Tags: php, class, oop, pagination

I have this pagination class which I converted from a normal procedural function to a class since I started learning OOP.  In the old procedural way, the function worked fine but I can't get this new class version to display on the screen

```
class Pagination {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * This function is called whenever the there are several records to be displayed in the table
     * This saves the page extending further down the page creating a long list of results
     * when all the results can be spread across multiple pages
     */
    public function pagination_one($total_pages, $page, $webpage) { 

        // Maximum number of links per page.  If exceeded, google style pagination is generated
        $max_links = 6; 
        $h=1; 
        if($page>$max_links) { 

            $h=(($h+$page)-$max_links); 
        } 
        if($page>=1) {
            $max_links = $max_links+($page-1); 
        } 
        if($max_links>$total_pages) {
            $max_links=$total_pages+1; 
        } 
        echo '<div class="page_numbers"> 
          <ul>'; 

        if($page>"1") { 
             echo '<li class="current"><a href="/'.$webpage.'/1">First</a></li> 
              <li class="current"><a href="/'.$webpage.'/'.($page-1).'">Prev</a></li> '; 
        } 

        if($total_pages!=1) {
                  for ($i=$h;$i<$max_links;$i++) { 
                if($i==$page) { 
                    echo '<li><a class="current">'.$i.'</a></li>'; 
                } 
                else 
                            { 
                    echo '<li><a href="/'.$webpage.'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> </li>'; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        if(($page >="1")&&($page!=$total_pages)) {

    echo '<li class="current"><a href="/'.$webpage.'/'.($page+1).'">Next</a></li> 
          <li class="current"><a href="/'.$webpage.'/'.$total_pages.'">Last</a></li>'; 
        } 
        echo '</ul> </div>'; 
    }
```

and elsewhere in another class I want to create a new instance of that class and pass the method in the return along with some parameters

```
public function paging() {
    if($this->getcount != 0) {
          $this->paging = new Pagination();
          return $this->paging->pagination_one($this->total_pages, $this->page, 'news');
        }
    }
```

When I try I var_dump() it comes up as NULL where I expect to see some pagination on the screen.

What have i got to change to be able to display the pagination?  Do I have to created some variables in the Pagination class for $total_pages, $page and $webpage and initialise them in the constructor and remove them from the pagination_one method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by removing the private variables in the class and changing the constructor.

The class now looks like this

```
class Pagination {

    public function __construct($total_pages, $page, $webpage) {

        $this->total_pages = $total_pages;
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->webpage = $webpage;
    }

    /**
     * This function is called whenever the there are several records to be displayed in the table
     * This saves the page extending further down the page creating a long list of results
     * when all the results can be spread across multiple pages
     */
    public function pagination_one() { 

        // Maximum number of links per page.  If exceeded, google style pagination is generated
        $max_links = 6; 
        $h = 1; 
        if($this->page > $max_links) { 

            $h=(($h + $this->page) - $max_links); 
        } 
        if($this->page >= 1) {

            $max_links = $max_links + ($this->page - 1); 
        } 
        if($max_links > $this->total_pages) {

            $max_links = $this->total_pages + 1; 
        } 

        $paging = '';

        $paging .= '<div class="page_numbers"> 
          <ul>'; 

        if($this->page > "1") { 

            $paging .= '<li class="current"><a href="/'.$this->webpage.'/1">First</a></li> 
                  <li class="current"><a href="/'.$this->webpage.'/'.($this->page - 1).'">Prev</a></li> '; 
        } 

        if($this->total_pages != 1) { 

            for ($i=$h; $i < $max_links; $i++) { 

                if($i == $this->page) { 

                    $paging .= '<li><a class="current">'.$i.'</a></li>'; 
                } 
                else { 

                    $paging .= '<li><a href="/'.$this->webpage.'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> </li>'; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        if(($this->page >= "1" ) && ($this->page != $this->total_pages)) {

            $paging .= '<li class="current"><a href="/'.$this->webpage.'/'.($this->page + 1).'">Next</a></li> 
                  <li class="current"><a href="/'.$this->webpage.'/'.$this->total_pages.'">Last</a></li>'; 
        } 

        $paging .= '</ul> </div>'; 

        return $paging;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that you fixed the problem by moving the variables to the constructor and assigning them to the class, which is a good strategy, but does not solve your initial problem. The reason your var_dump was showing NULL, was because you weren't returning anything in your function, instead you were only using echo, which prints directly to the page. The reason that your problem was solved is because you changed all the echo calls to a return :)

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
return $this->paging->pagination_one...
```

when you are not returning anything in `pagination_one` -method, hence null.

Comment: So how do i print out my paging?

Answer (score 0):

```
function pagination($sql_total_row, $post_per_page,$current_page=1, $url='', $lasturl = '', $parameter ='paging') {
    $number_page = ceil($sql_total_row / $post_per_page);if($number_page<=1) return false;
    $uls ='<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">';
    $a = parse_url($url);
    if(isset($a['query']))$url .= '&';else $url .= '?';
    $url .= $parameter.'=';

    $urls = '';
    $distanc = 5;
    $f = $current_page-$distanc;
    $l = $current_page+$distanc;
    $li = function($n,$link,$current_page){ return $current_page==$n ? '<li class="active"><span>'.$n.'</span><li>' : '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$n.'</a></li>'; };

    for ($i = $current_page; $i > 0; $i--){
        if($i>$f or $i < $distanc)
            $urls = $li($i,$url.$i.$lasturl,$current_page). $urls;
        else{
            $i = $distanc;
            $urls = '<li><span>...</span><li>'.$urls;
        }
    }

    for ($i = $current_page+1; $i < $number_page; $i++){
        if($i<$l or $i > $number_page - $distanc)
            $urls .= $li($i,$url.$i.$lasturl,$current_page);
        else{
            $i = $number_page - $distanc;
            $urls.= '<li><span>...</span><li>';
        }
    }
    return $uls.$urls.'</ul>';
}
```

usage:

```
$total_row_sql = 1500; //required - get from mysql: SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
$row_display = 50; //required
$parameter_paged = (isset($_GET['paging'])) ? $_GET['paging'] : 1; // required
$custom_url = '/wordpress_url/?'; //custom
$hash = '#target_element_id'; //custom
$name_paramerter_paging = 'paging'; //custom

echo pagination($total_row_sql,$row_display,$parameter_paged,$custom_url,$hash,$name_paramerter_paging);
```

Result:
[view result using pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQCNP.png)

========================================================================
**Example if using loop from database:**

```
function select( $table, $field='*', $where='', $order='') {
    $sql = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $field from $table";
    if($where) $sql.= " where $where";
    if($order) $sql.= " order by $order";
    $items = $wordpress_mysql->get_results( $sql );// custom: default result object, if u want parse array: ( $sql, ARRAY_A);
    $sql_posts_total = $wordpress_mysql->get_var( "SELECT FOUND_ROWS();" );
    return (object)['result'=>$items, 'total_rows'=>$sql_posts_total];
}
$result = select('user');

$data_items = $result->result;// foreach show database if u want

$sql_posts_total = $result->total_rows;
$post_per_page = 50;
$parameter_paged = (isset($_GET['paging'])) ? $_GET['paging'] : 1;
echo pagination($sql_posts_total,$post_per_page,$parameter_paged);
```